# Unable to build package Python

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, twine

I am unable to build my Python package. I have barely changed any code and it used to work months ago. When running `python setup.py sdist` it doesn't create a new `.tar` file for the package distribution. I have installed `twine` and `setuptools` already.

File tree 
[image]

Setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

with open("README.md", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    readme = f.read()

setup(
    name="rolimons",
    version="2.6.4",
    author="walker",
    description="Rolimons API Wrapper",
    long_description=readme,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=['rolimons'],
    url="https://github.com/wa1ker38552/rolimons.py",
    install_requires=["requests", "bs4"],
    python_requires=">=3.7",
    py_modules=["rolimons"]
)
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working even though it worked a few months ago?
I have tried updating all the packages and checked that `setup.py` is located in the right place but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get any terminal output when you run that command?

Comment: Did you activate your venv before trying to build the package?

Comment: What command have you issued? What is the error?

Comment: I don't get any terminal output even when I add verbose mode, I don't know what activate your venv means? Could you explain? I issued only `python setup.py sdist` and nothing more. There is no error the command just runs and doesn't output anything.